# Editing a comment and retaining formatting using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I  have a workbook where i am comparing two worksheets that should be identical for the most part, including comments. When there is a difference, I am marking the cell yellow in the main sheet and then creating a formatted comment with details on what is different. That cell will now have BOTH comments.

As many of the cells have formatted comments already, I have created a function that inserts a new comment at the end of an existing comment and keeps the formatting of both comments.

Below is the code for what i have. This would be called after i compare the comment text of the two fields and determine they are different.

The code seems to work fine. However copying one character at a is inefficient. I would be able to insert the comment with something like TF.Characters(TF.Characters.Count+1).Insert (DiffR.Comment.text). But how can i copy over the font structure for the bold and size formatting of the comment with a single statement using SOMETHING LIKE TF.Characters(start position before the copy,start position before the copy + copytf.characters.count).Font = CopyTF(0,copytf.characters.count).font? This doesn't seem to work...

```
Public Sub AddDifferentComment(R As Range, DiffR As Range)
Dim TF As TextFrame, CopyTF As TextFrame, theChar As String
Dim SeparatorStr As String
Dim i As Integer

SeparatorStr = Chr(10) & "---------------------------" & Chr(10)


Set TF = R.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
Set CopyTF = DiffR.Comment.Shape.TextFrame

TF.Characters(TF.Characters.Count).Insert (SeparatorStr)

For i = 1 To CopyTF.Characters.Count
    theChar = CopyTF.Characters(i, 1).text
    TF.Characters(TF.Characters.Count + 1).Insert (theChar)
    TF.Characters(TF.Characters.Count).Font.Bold = CopyTF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
    TF.Characters(TF.Characters.Count).Font.Size = CopyTF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
Next i
End Sub
```

Another way to view this is: Is there an efficient way to make one comment equal to FORMATTED comments of two different cells, concatenated?

I also tried to do this with storing arrays of characters as the format changed, which works but is surprisingly slow when i review the character by character.  If this could be sped up it would be fine.

```
Public Sub GetFormattedStringsFromComment(R As Range, ByRef strCommentA() As String, ByRef bBoldA() As Boolean, ByRef theSizeA() As Integer, ArrayCount As Integer)
Dim TF As TextFrame
Dim i As Integer, bLastBold As Boolean, LastSize As Integer, bNewFormat As Boolean, theStr As String

    If Not HasComment(R) Then Exit Sub

    i = -1
    Do While strCommentA(i + 1) <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ArrayCount = i

    Set TF = R.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
    For i = 1 To TF.Characters.Count
        If i > 1 Then
            'Check to see if it is a changed format and if so add to the arrays
            If bLastBold <> TF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Or LastSize <> TF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size Then
                ArrayCount = ArrayCount + 1
                strCommentA(ArrayCount) = theStr
                bBoldA(ArrayCount) = bLastBold
                theSizeA(ArrayCount) = LastSize
                theStr = ""
            End If
        End If
        theStr = theStr & TF.Characters(i, 1).text
        bLastBold = TF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
        LastSize = TF.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
    Next i
    ArrayCount = ArrayCount + 1
    strCommentA(ArrayCount) = theStr
    bBoldA(ArrayCount) = bLastBold
    theSizeA(ArrayCount) = LastSize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This changes all new characters at once (if the new comment is only one font size, and Bold)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddDifferentComment(ByRef toRng As Range, ByRef newRng As Range)
    Dim toTxt As TextFrame, newTxt As TextFrame, newStart As Long, divLine As String

    divLine = Chr(10) & "---------------------------" & Chr(10)

    Set newTxt = newRng.Comment.Shape.TextFrame
    Set toTxt = toRng.Comment.Shape.TextFrame

    newStart = toTxt.Characters.Count + Len(divLine) + 1

    toRng.Comment.Text divLine & newTxt.Characters.Text, newStart

    With toTxt.Characters(newStart, newTxt.Characters.Count + 1).Font
        .Size = newTxt.Characters.Font.Size
        .Bold = newTxt.Characters.Font.Bold
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I haven't measured it but it's probably faster